# Elements of array are fixed-length while array itself is not

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
var data = List();
snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) => data.add(doc.data)); //my example data is one doc
data.add({"x": "y"}); //works
data[0]["bar"].add({"foo": "bar"}); //doesn't
```

My data looks like this:

```
  data = [
    {
      "foo": "",
      "bar": [
        {"foo": "bar"},
        {"foo": "bar"},
        {"foo": "bar"},
      ],
    },
  ];
```

When I do the second array modification, it gives me this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to a fixed-length list
```

I have tried doing this with normal data that is not fetched from firebase, and it works as expected. I also tried using List.from to populate the array but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snapshot.data.documents[0]['bar']` apparently is a fixed-length (i.e., non-growable) `List`.  You can't make a non-growable `List` growable.  You instead need to create a growable *copy*:

```dart
data[0]["bar"] = data[0]["bar"].toList(); // Create a copy.
data[0]["bar"].add({"foo": "bar"}); // Now this should work.
```

Alternatively:

```dart
data[0]["bar"] = [...data[0]["bar"], {"foo": "bar"}];
```

However, while the latter approach is more compact, it is less clear that the copy is explicitly desired.

Comment: Thanks. This was the issue. It works now. Is there any other way of fixing it by forcing the data to be growable upon adding it to the array?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
var data = List();
var data2= List();

snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) => data.add(doc.data)); //my example data is one doc
data.add({"x": "y"}); //works

data2=data[0]["bar"];
data2.add({"foo": "bar"});
```

Comment: `data2 = List()` is pointless if you're just going to reassign it later, and adding the `data2` variable won't change a fixed-length `List` to a growable one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *add* method is used over an object type. You need to add a cast before using *add* method:

```
  (data[0]["bar"] as List<Map<String, String>>).add({"foo": "bar"});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the static type is `dynamic`.  Otherwise there would probably be a different error about there not being an `add` method.  The error message clearly indicates that the problem is that the OP is trying to modify a fixed-length `List`, not a growable one.